# ActionMailer will not send mail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am trying to set up a simple contact_us page in my dev environment where a user can send an inquiry using a form I have created. I have ActiveMailer and the Contact model/controller/view all set up but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Any ideas? My log appears to show mail being sent.

ActionMailer

```
class ContactConfirmation < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def receipt(contact)
    @contact = contact

    mail to: 'myname@example.com',
      subject: contact.subject
  end
end
```

Receipt

```
<%= @contact.first_name %> <%= @contact.last_name %>

Writes:

<%= @contact.description %>
```

ContactsController

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.submit_contact_info
      redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Submission successful. Somebody will get back to you shortly.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  protected

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :subject, :description)
  end
end
```

Contact Model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i }
  validates_presence_of :subject
  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name

  def submit_contact_info
    if save
      ContactConfirmation.receipt(self).deliver
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

Contact Form rendered in the contacts/new.html.erb file

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :last_name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :subject %>
  <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit Contact Form' %>
<% end %>
```

In Initializers folder I have an smtp.rb file:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: "localhost",
    port: 1025
  }
end
```

After changing my config now getting the following error on `ContactConfirmation.receipt(self).deliver`:

Errno::ECONNREFUSED in ContactsController#create
Connection refused - connect(2)

```
def submit_contact_info
    if save
      ContactConfirmation.receipt(self).deliver
      return true
    end
  end
```

Comment: Mails in development aren't send by default, can you add `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` to your config,restart and check again?

Comment: Have you got your SMTP details all set up?

Comment: @zrl3dx now getting error: Connection refused - connect(2) def submit_contact_info
    if save
      ContactConfirmation.receipt(self).deliver
      return true
    end
  end

Comment: @RichPeck I added my smtp settings to the above question

Comment: @oddone: so as you can see, you have got wrong setup, is your mail server working on port 1025? Default (at least in postfix) is 25. Can you paste output of `telnet localhost 1025`?

Comment: hm ok, I think it may be on 1025 for mail catcher testing. Should I change my settings? The output is: telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: If you're using `mailcatcher` (which works on 1025 port, indeed) you should start it by `mailcatcher`, visit `localhost:1080` and check if  you see its web interface or connection refused error.

Comment: @zrl3dx when i try mail again now I get ==> SMTP: Received message from '<from@example.com>' (296 bytes). does this mean it is working properly?

Comment: Probably yes, you should see that email on `localhost:1080`. If it's working now write it so I can sum up those comments and add them as answer.

Comment: Yes i believe it is working now. Thanks very much for your help. It still does not deliver mail to my inbox but that is because of mail catcher, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let's start from the beginning:

In development mode mails aren't delivered by default and delivery errors aren't raised, that's why you get no error and no email. To change this add the following to your config **and restart server**:

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true 
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Now you should either get some error or get an email. As you've wrote in comments, you received `Connection refused` error so it means your mailer deamon is not running. You're using [mailcatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/) (hence 1025 port) so after installing it you should run it by simple `mailcatcher`. Now you should get no errors and you should be able to see your email after browsing to `localhost:1080`.